# Call stored procedure (sending mails) in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I´m working with Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008, I created an application that sends mails, now my query is a simple select, but I need make it with a stored procedure, how can I replace that select for a stored procedure?

Here is my code:

```
public List<string> SqlSelectMails()
{
    List<string> dir_mails = new List<string>();

    **string stSql = "select mail_usuario from dbo.mail_usuario_v2 where n_visita=0 and   
    aviso=1 order by banca";**

    Bd mibd = new Bd();
    SqlDataReader sdr = mibd.sqlExecute(stSql);

    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        dir_mails.Add(sdr["mail_usuario"].ToString());
    }
    return dir_mails;
}
```

I will like something like:

```
**string stSql = "exec pa_rep_mail";**
```

Comment: Exactly why do you need to make this a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to create the stored procedure in your database (using Sql Management Studio)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_rep_mail]
AS
    select mail_usuario 
    from dbo.mail_usuario_v2 
    where n_visita=0 and aviso=1 
    order by banca
```

then you need to call it from your code

```
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(constring))
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("pa_rep_mail", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
      dir_mails.Add(sdr["mail_usuario"].ToString());
    }
}
```

of course it is up to you to integrate this code in your existing code. In particular how to replace the call to `mibd.sqlExecute(stSql);`